# nvd3 - how to set y axis to default values

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I tho this was a pretty common requirement for a chart library, but I couldn't figure out how to achieve this.

I have a `multichart`(bars,area and lines) which displays time on the x-axis and temperature on the y-axis.

My max temperature across all the data series I've got is 22, and so my y-axis goes from 0 to 22. Can I make it to be ALWAYS from 0 to 100?

I tried with:

```
forceY = [0,100]
yAxis1.domain([0,100])
```

But all I get is from 0 to my max.

Suggestions?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `yDomain1:[0,100]`

working plunk [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/628Ni0?p=preview)